# Start a Tomcat service through programmatically

Tags: java, apache, tomcat7

sorry ,for asking silly doubt 
i am using zip version of apache tamcat,
 when i manually start means( by clicking startup.bat)  tomcat service is start no problem , 
But if i am going to start through java program it showing below error

**"The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program "**

Code Snippet:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        Process p1 = runtime.exec("cmd /c start D:\\Apache_Tomcat64\\bin\\startup.bat");
        InputStream is = p1.getInputStream();
        int i = 0;
        while( (i = is.read() ) != -1) {
            System.out.print((char)i);
        }
    } catch(IOException ioException) {
        System.out.println(ioException.getMessage() );
    }
```

i am thinking that issue is Run as Administrator
but i don't know how to handle it 
please any advice or solution
Thanks for advance

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in working directory location.

When you running startup.bat it tries to find a catalina.bat file in a directory where you started your Java class but not in a directory where Tomcat located.

You can try modify your code with next manner

```
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            File workingDirectory = new File("D:\\Apache_Tomcat64\\bin");
            Process p1 = runtime.exec("cmd /c start D:\\Apache_Tomcat64\\bin\\startup.bat", new String[0], workingDirectory);
            InputStream is = p1.getInputStream();
            int i = 0;
            while( (i = is.read() ) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char)i);
            }
        } catch(IOException ioException) {
            System.out.println(ioException.getMessage() );
        }
    }
```